# VB vs C#: Why is this possible?

Tags: c#, vb.net, casting

Here is some code that troubles me every time I think about it.

```vb
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        For Each i As Integer In New String() {"why", "is", "this", "tolerated?"}
            ' compiles just fine.
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

C# simply will not allow converting strings to integers implicitly.

```cs
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        foreach (int i in new string[] {"that's", "better"}) {
            // will not compile, and for good reason.
        }
    }
}
```

Why does VB let us do that?  I'm trying to have fun with this because I'm still relatively new here, but I'm also genuinely curious.  I'm sure there are devs out there with the answer.

Comment: I included the `Option Strict` statement in the post and it's supposed to restrict type conversions to widening conversions and disallow implicit typing, yet it still compiles.

Comment: @mellamokb, as the OP has shown, this works even with `Option Strict On`.

Comment: That's a good point. According to [this blog post](http://www.owenpellegrin.com/articles/vb-net/converting-strings-to-numbers/) even with `Option Strict Off` it should not allow implicit conversion of strings that are not valid numeric values, so something else must be happening here.  **EDIT**: I just tested this quickly with LINQPad and it doesn't seem to compile... where are you testing this where you don't get compiler errors?

Comment: I wonder whether it's because, in VB, that "cast" is actually done using `CType` rather than `DirectCast`, which would be the direct equivalent of what happens in C#.  `CType` can coerce values of certain types to certain other types and `String` to `Integer` is one combination that is supported.  One clue to that being the case is that you get the same exception thrown at run time when you run your code and when you use `CType` to try to convert a non-numeric `String` to an `Integer`.

Comment: it compiles on my computer but gives an `InvalidCastExecption` when I run it.

Comment: @MarkHall Of course, because you can't cast `"why"` to an integer. Change the strings to `{"0", "1", "2"}` and it should cast just fine.

Comment: @scottyeatscode I am well aware of that, was just stating it catches it at runtime, I do not know why it doesn't at compile time.

Comment: @MarkHall Exactly! It's bewildering!

Comment: @MarkHall Please pardon my crass response.

Comment: Kudos for doing the "question out of curiosity" well. Very interesting one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears to be a idiosyncrasy of the [`For Each`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) Statement. According to the documentation it is evaluated at Runtime.

From Link:

> When Option Strict is set to On, narrowing conversions ordinarily cause compiler errors. In a For Each statement, however, conversions from the elements in group to element are evaluated and performed at run time, and compiler errors caused by narrowing conversions are suppressed.
>
> In the following example, the assignment of m as the initial value for n doesn't compile when Option Strict is on because the conversion of a Long to an Integer is a narrowing conversion. In the For Each statement, however, no compiler error is reported, even though the assignment to number requires the same conversion from Long to Integer. In the For Each statement that contains a large number, a run-time error occurs when ToInteger is applied to the large number.

Answer (score 11):

Microsoft apologizes for this in the Language Specification, chapter 10.9:

> The current element of the iteration is converted to the type of the loop control variable even if the conversion is explicit because there is no convenient place to introduce a conversion operator in the statement. This became particularly troublesome when working with the most common collection type, System.Collections.ArrayList, because its element type is Object. This would have required casts in a great many loops, something we felt was not ideal.
>   Ironically, generics enabled the creation of a strongly-typed collection, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T), which might have made us rethink this design point, but for compatibility’s sake, this cannot be changed now.

Answer (score 6):

As a supplement to Mark's answer, here's how the compiled `vb.net` code looks like. As you can see the code is compiled to a [For...Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) statement and the error occurs only at run-time when trying to convert the string to integer.

```vb
Dim VB$t_array$L0 As String() = New String() { "why", "is", "this", "tolerated?" }
Dim VB$t_i4$L0 As Integer
For VB$t_i4$L0 = 0 To VB$t_array$L0.Length - 1
    Dim i As Integer = Conversions.ToInteger(VB$t_array$L0(VB$t_i4$L0))
Next VB$t_i4$L0
```

Comment: How were you able to view what the code turned into like that? I can't do it in Reflector 8.

Comment: If you have the desktop application you should be able to drag and drop the executable file onto the assembly treeview.

Comment: Everything looks very readable to me, and in C#. Is that what the decompilation looks like after obfuscation?

Comment: @scottyeatscode You're looking at the [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code converted *back* to vb.net. There's no obfuscation, the variable names are auto-generated by the compiler. I don't know the exact algorithm used, but for instance, the part `i4` will turn into `i2` for a 16 bit signed integer (short) and `i8` for a 64 bit signed integer (long).

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I appreciate it. Still learning and growing as a developer. So all of this is good for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Am I the only one that can see that in the VB code the array is a generic(variant) array while the C# code contains strict string array ?

Comment: I've updated the code so that they're both "strict string arrays". The code still shows no compile time errors. Mark Hall, Bjorn-Roger Kringsja, and Hans Passant have already provided more than enough information to explain why this behavior occurs.

Comment: In fact, if you look at Bjorn-Roger Kringsja's answer, the list of strings ultimately becomes an array of strings.